# Image appears resized automatically

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, image

When I drop in the third image, it is showing up shorter than the rest. When  I replace the image name with say the Serendipity image it doesn't appear shorter. All images are `1200X800`.

```
<!--Start design section-->
<a id="design">
<div class="container-fluid designContainer text-center">
  <img class="img-fluid sectionIMG" src="images/design.png" alt="design">
  <div class="container-fluid text-center">
    <div class="row justify-content-md-center">
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12 project">
        <div class="hovereffect">
          <img class="img-fluid projectIcon" src="images/logo_serendipity.png" alt="serendipity">
          <div class="overlay">
            <h2>Serendipity Coffee & Tea</h2>
            <p>A small, family owned, cafe in the heart of Osage County.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12 project">
        <div class="hovereffect">
          <img class="img-fluid projectIcon" src="images/logo_audrey.jpg" alt="Audrey Collins">
          <div class="overlay">
            <h2>Audrey Collins</h2>
            <p>A rising pop artist located in Seattle, WA</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12 project">
        <div class="hovereffect">
          <img class="img-fluid projectIcon" src="images/p2p.jpg" alt="P2P">
          <div class="overlay">
            <h2>Point to Point Transportation</h2>
            <p>A rising pop artist located in Seattle, WA</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!--End design Section-->
```

[JsFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/z42drp3o/)

Notice the far right image appears shorter even though everything is the extact same except the image link.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that all images are in same height? When I updated your jsfiddle it properly showed all three images.

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/z42drp3o/10/)

Comment: @ManojDeMel I noticed that too when I reused one of the other images. When I looked at the properties of the image it said it was 1200x800 but after opening in illustrator, there was some issues with transparency. Thanks